# How to communicate between micro controller and Digital signal processor?

Tags: avr

I am working on some project where I need to communicate between **two processors** (hardware), **ATxMEGA128A1** AVR Controller and **Blackfin BF522** Digital Signal Processor. Someone help me.

Comment: Find interfaces that common between them and they can communicate (either peer-peer, master-slave, etc.) If there are no such interfaces, check if there are widely used interfaces like I2C, RS-232, CAN, etc. that can be emulated with these processors and connect to them using cheap measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, to communicate between a **DSP** and a **UController** you can use asynchronous serial link **USART** that's called as **Inter-Processor Communication(IPC)**.
You can code for GPIO pins if you know how to write code for **USART**,that's available on almost any UController.

In-short you need **USART** channel to communicate between **DSP** and UController(IPC).That's the one possible way I don't know about others.